# How do I automatically create sub folders when I create a new folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online

My document library has a folder labeled "clients". What I would like to happen; every time I create a new "Client Name" folder within clients, how do I get subfolders to automatically generate? For example, John Smith's file has "Orders", "Plaintiff filings", "Defendant filings", etc. I want those to automatically generate when I create a client file.

Answer (score 1):

The below CSOM code worked for me.

```
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("My List");

var folder = list.RootFolder;
clientContext.Load(folder);

// This will create the Root Folder in the library
folder = folder.Folders.Add("Parent-Folder");  

//This will create the sub-folder inside the folder created from above code
var nestedFolder = folder.Folders.Add("Child1-Folder");
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Hope it helps you too.

Comment: This works providing the joint length of parent and child folder names is 128-characters or less, otherwise you get an ArgumentException. I'm trying to figure out how to do it if the parent and child names are individually 128-characters or less.